# xpath Query for selecting a single node from a list of similar nodes

Tags: xml, xpath, expression

I have a list of nodes as given below:

```
<Vector>
<Point z="0" y="0" x="0"/>
<Point z="3.000" y="2.000" x="1.000"/>
<Point z="6.000" y="5.000" x="4.000"/>
</Vector>
```

I would like to select the third node i.e. where x = 4 from the above list and then update its x-value. I have tried using this as the xpath query: "/Vector/Point[3]" from [this](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_examples.asp) but it doesn't work. Is there any other way I could do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the 3rd child, try:

```
/Vector/Point[position()=3]
```

To get based on the value of `x` attribute:

```
/Vector/Point[@x="4.000"]
```

Comment: That will work for this case but what if I have two x's with 4.000 as their values?

Comment: `/Vector/Point[3]` works for me. Try `/Vector/Point[position()=3]`

Comment: For some reason, even this is not working for me. I'm not sure if this is a problem with my app or in general. I can see it works on the website and for you, which is why I'm a bit surprised.

Comment: I sort of did something similar along the lines of your answer:/Vector/Point[@x="4.000"][@y="5.000"][@z="6.000"] and it worked.